# Accessing Jpanel from another method in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am new to java. And Most of my questions here are going unanswered, I don't know what is wrong with my question. I hope this question gets some answer.

So, Now I am creating a frame, this frame contains tabbedPane and tabbedPane contains two JPanels. All this is done in one function `createAndShowGUI()`

And there is another function which is creating buttons with for loop, and I want to add this new buttons to my `JPanel panel`. Here is my code. I want to add buttons creating in `createButton()` method to panel created in `createAndShowGUI()` method

```
public class Try extends JFrame {

    static Connection conn;
    //JPanel panel;
    static JButton buttons;
    static int totalRows;
    static int recordPerPage = 1000000;
    static int totalPages = 0;

    private static JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    protected static void createAndShowGUI() throws SQLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.lightGray);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frame.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("TABLE", null, panel, null);
        tabbedPane.setFont( new Font( "Dialog", Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC, 16 ) );
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("GRAPH", null, panel_1, null);
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.white);

        JTable table = new JTable();
        panel.add(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        createDBConnection();
    }

    private static void createDBConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_temp/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        createPaginationButtons(conn);
    }

    private static void createPaginationButtons(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM cdr");
        while (rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getInt(1)); 
            totalRows = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        int v = totalRows % recordPerPage == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        totalPages = totalRows / recordPerPage + v;
        createButton(totalPages);

    }

    private static void createButton(int totalPages) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, totalPages);
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPages;) {
            buttons = new JButton(""+(i+1) );
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, buttons);
            panel.add(buttons);
            i++;
        }


    }

}
```

Any idea, how to do this ?

Comment: Your methods are `void`. Refactor them to return some `JPanel` object and use in desired method

Comment: *"Most of my questions here are going unanswered, I don't know what is wrong with my question"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Remove all the DB stuff and hard code some data if data is truly needed to demonstrate the problem. General advice: Don't extend `JFrame` or other GUI components.

Comment: I removed `extends JFrame` and its working now. THANKS MATE !!